# Natural Language Processing (NLP) with Java

Tags: java, nlp

I'm starting a project in which sentiment analysis is going to take center stage. Specifically, we'll be doing sentiment analysis of Twitter, Facebook, YouTube and other social network data.

I know of OpenNLP from Apache. It appears great but I think it's a little heavyweight for what I want to do in addition to it's dependence on Hadoop and the like. I haven't used it before and I may be wrong in my assessment of it.

I've seen elsewhere on this site about Stanford NLP. I can't seem to get a good starting point with this library; a tutorial sort of.

Also, I've read about Sentiment Anaysis APIs like AlchemyAPI on this site, but I want a solution I'm fully in control of. I just want a library I can bundle with my application.

In a nut shell I'm looking for a solution that is lightweight, and that I can set up in my local PC. Also, a pointer to a good starting point for Stanford NLP or OpenNLP will be appreciated very much.

**UPDATE:**

I've gone through the UIMA documentation and its support for components like OpenNLP components and other third party components, in addition to its inbuilt text processing capabilities makes it an attractive starting point. It's open architecture makes me feel it's ideal for what I want to achieve. Additional recommendation or advice will still be appreciated very much.

Comment: OpenNLP does not depend on Hadoop. I'd consider it more lightweight than UIMA (although you cannot really compare them).

Comment: I'm thinking of starting with UIMA and then plugging in OpenNLP when I need it. I've also seen UIMA has support for several other components for text processing. As such, I guess starting with UIMA will enable mr take advantage of these components when I do need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at:

[SenticNet](http://sentic.net/)

[CLIPS](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#sentiment)

All of these are easy to integrate with Python. You also can use NLTK, a great library for doing NLP.

Comment: Thanks @George. The links are great and help shade light on a number of fronts in social data text analysis. I'm, however, looking for a Java or Scala-based solution.